# Calculating distance and/or time taken to travel from population centre to nearest hospital in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, routing

I'm trying to find out how long it would take to travel by car from each of the Lower Layer Super Output Areas (LSOA) in Norfolk, England to the nearest Hospital (or just what the distance is and I can estimate drive time, if the former is too difficult/impossible!).

Any suggestions how I can do that using QGIS, OSM road data and/or [Ordnance Survey Meridian 2 road data](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/meridian2/), [population weighted centroids for each of the 2011 Census LSOA areas](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/guide-method/geography/products/census/spatial/centroids/index.html) and hospital locations?

I have all of the above in QGIS (see image below).

There are 537 LSOA and four hospitals in total. Is there a way to work out the time taken and/or distance to travel without having to do it one by one?

[image]

Comment: Did you look into [anita graser examples of pgrouting](http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/09/creating-catchment-areas-with-pgrouting-and-qgis/). Take also a look into [GRASS network functions] (http://jcastellssala.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/basic-network-analysis-with-grass/).

Comment: Are you able to do a bit of Python scripting?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a [presentation (PDF)](http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~gisteac/proceedingsonline/GISRUK2013/gisruk2013_submission_13.pdf) at GISRUK'13 that made use of [Routino](http://www.routino.org/) to solve a similar problem. It makes use of the OpenStreetMap road network but I think you should be able to change that if you install it locally. But for your size of problem you could probably script the solution using the web api.

Answer (score 1):

You can call our [RW Net 4](http://www.routeware.dk/rwnet4/rwnet.php) library from python. We have a working sample, that does something quite similar to what you describe above and it can also use [Meridian 2](http://www.routeware.dk/download.php), which we also offer in a free and improved version. The sample uses QGIS and [Python.NET](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/) for the operations.